# Struggling to understand the subtlety of relectToAttribute

Tags: polymer

I am struggling to understand the subtlety of reflectToAttribute on a Polymer elements property.

I have an pair of elements for transmitting values around the dom tree like `iron-meta` which I have called `akc-meta` and `akc-meta-query`.  In my test fixture I am doing this

```
<test-fixture id="basic-test">
<template>
  <template is="dom-bind" id=app>
    <akc-meta key="[[key1]]" value="{{value1}}" id="meta1"></akc-meta>
    <akc-meta-query key="[[key2]]" value="{{value2}}" id="meta2"></akc-meta-query>
    <akc-meta-query key="[[key3]]" value="{{value3}}" id="meta3"></akc-meta-query>
    <akc-meta key="[[key4]]" value="{{value4}}" id="meta4"></akc-meta>
  </template>
</template>
</test-fixture>
```

and in my test suite I can set values like this

```
      app.key1 = 'keya';
      app.key2 = 'keya';
      app.key3 = 'keya';
      app.value1 = 'This is a multiple query test';
      expect(app.value2).to.equal('This is a multiple query test');
      expect(app.value3).to.equal('This is a multiple query test');
      app.value1 = 'New Value';
      expect(app.value2).to.equal('New Value');
      expect(app.value3).to.equal('New Value');
```

where these elements transmit values under the hood between the elements when the keys are the same.

Neither of the elements use reflectToAttribute on any of the properties, although the `value` property of `akc-meta-query` does use `notify:true`

So what does reflectToAttribute actually do and why do you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a small example in [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/soluho/edit?html,output).

```
<style>   
    x-test {
      display: block;
    }
    x-test[prop1="initialvalue1"] {
      border: 5px solid yellow;
    }
    x-test[prop2="initialvalue2"] {
      background: green;
    }
    x-test[prop1="newvalue1"] {
      border: 5px solid black;
    }
    x-test[prop2="newvalue2"] {
      background: red;
    }


</style>
<dom-module id="x-test">
  <template>
    <div>{{prop1}}</div>
    <div>{{prop2}}</div>
    <button on-click="update1">Update Prop1</button>
    <button  on-click="update2">Update Prop2</button>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-test',
      properties:{
        prop1: {
          type:String
        },
        prop2: {
          type:String,
          reflectToAttribute: true
        },
      },
      update1: function(){
        this.prop1 = "newvalue1";
      },
      update2: function(){
        this.prop2 = "newvalue2";
      }      
    });
  });
</script>

<x-test prop1="initialvalue1" prop2="initialvalue2"></x-test>
```

The element here has two properties. `prop1` is not reflected to the attribute, but `prop2` is. Both are set to an initial value. If you open the developer tools, you will see something like this:
[image: Before updating the properties]

There is an update button to change either `prop1` or `prop2`. If you click each button and update both properties, you will get this picture[image: After updating the properties]

As you can see, `prop1` still has its old state. The state change has not been reflected back to the attribute. In contrast, `prop2` has been reflected and has changed.

Now if you access either property through JavaScript, you will get the updated value. However, when you access the HTML attribute, in case of `prop1` you will not.

A use case for this could be when you have CSS rules with attribute selectors as in my example. The selector `x-test[prop1="newvalue1"]` does not apply when `prop1` is updated. On the other hand `x-test[prop2="newvalue2"]` does apply after the update of `prop2`, because it is configured to reflect to attribute.

Comment: I think what you are saying is that its the css that might need the attribute reflected?

Comment: Yes, at least that's the first use case for reflecting to attribute that I can think of.